# Maven executing all testng suites instead of single testng suite

Tags: maven, testng, allure

In below folder
src/test/resources/testngsuites,

I have three testng xml file. I am passing specific testng xml during execution as below:

mvn clean test -DdefaultSuiteFiles=src/test/resources/testngsuites/UserIdentification.xml

But it is running all testng xml files available in that path.

My POM file:

```
    <properties\>
    <defaultSuiteFiles\>sampletestng.xml\</defaultSuiteFiles\>
    <suiteFile\>${defaultSuiteFiles}\</suiteFile\>  
    </properties\>

`<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${maven-surefire-plugin.version}</version>
    <configuration>
     <systemPropertyVariables>
                    <allure.results.directory>target/allure-results</allure.results.directory>
     </systemPropertyVariables>

     <suiteXmlFiles>
                    <suiteXmlFile>${defaultSuiteFiles}</suiteXmlFile>
     </suiteXmlFiles>

     <argLine>
                    -javaagent:"${settings.localRepository}/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/${aspectj.version}/aspectjweaver-${aspectj.version}.jar"
     </argLine>
      </configuration>
  <dependencies>
 <dependency>
 <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
 <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
 <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
 </dependency>
 </dependencies>
  </plugin>`
```

I have played with different options like directly defining parameter in plugin instead of properties and passed from command line but no luck.

```
`<suiteXmlFiles\>

 <!-- Pass testng.xml files as argument from command line -->

    <suiteXmlFile>${suiteXmlFile}</suiteXmlFile>

</suiteXmlFiles\>`
```

Tried this :

mvn clean test -Dsurefire.suiteXmlFiles=src/test/resources/testngsuites/UserIdentification.xml

And tried this:

mvn clean test -DsuiteXmlFile=src/test/resources/testngsuites/UserIdentification.xml

I have downgraded maven allure and maven  compile plugin and tried but not luck.